# WL is not defined error mfpf 8.0

Tags: init, mfp

Any solutions for the above error?

Below is the code.

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    WL.Client.init=function(wlInitOptions){
    // Application logic.
    require(['app'], function(app){});  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ibm-mfp-web-sdk` folder to `node_modules` folder from `Node_Server` folder.